Concat headings for each row where cell value for that row and heading is true
I have a table like so:


This example has only 5 rows but the real data set will have a variable number of rows.
This example has only 3 columns (b, c, d) but the real data will have 30+ columns.

I want to add a column to the end that, for each row, shows a concatanated list of headings where the cell for that row and heading is true.
The expected output would be something like:

I know I need to use ARRAYFORMULA or BYROW to go through each row, but then I can't figure out how to take the values of each row, check if it's TRUE, then get the heading.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Tldr: Images are hard to copy.

@TheMaster Got it. Thanks. Also, there is https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for making MD tables.

Use Map (Together with other functions)
You may use the following:
=MAP(B2:B6,C2:C6,D2:D6,LAMBDA(x,y,z,Join(",",split(if(x=true,B1&".","")&if(y=true,C1&".","")&if(z=true,D1&".",""),"."))))

Given:

Update
For now, I have created a custom function for this scenario. I used double Map and filter to achieve required results.
function customFunction(data) {
  data.map(x=>x.shift());
  var header = data.shift();
  return data.map(x=>[x.map((y,i)=>x[i]?header[i]:"").filter(z=>z).join(",")]);
}

Usage:

=customFunction(range of your data)

Output:
Initial Sample:

Expanded Sample:

Update 2:
I have come up with the Google Sheets Formula by using BYROW and BYCOL:
=BYROW(B2:D6,LAMBDA(x,JOIN(",",SPLIT(JOIN(",",BYCOL(x,LAMBDA(y,if(y=true,index(1:1,1,COLUMN(y)),"")))),","))))

Note: You just need to change the range B2:B6
Output:
Sample Output:

Expanded Output:


I am sorry, I forgot to include one important part in the question. I've updated the question. This example has only 3 columns (b, c, d) but the real data will have 30+ columns.

Oh, I see. That changes everything. Let me work on it.

I think this will be easier with Google Apps Script by creating a custom function due to its complexity. But I will still try to create a Google Sheets Formula for this.

@IMTheNachoMan I have finally achieved the Google Sheets Formula which is already in the Update 2 section. Kindly check if it works on your end.


You may try:
=byrow(B2:Z,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,join(", ",ifna(filter(B1:Z1,Σ))))))



=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(IF(B2:C8,B1:C1,),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",1,r))))


IF does the heavy work of getting the correct header for all the TRUEs in the array.
Once we have the headers, we aggregate rows using TEXTJOIN, BY each ROW.




a
b
c
Output




1
TRUE
TRUE
b,c


2
FALSE
FALSE



3
TRUE
FALSE
b


4
FALSE
TRUE
c


5
TRUE
FALSE
b


6
FALSE
TRUE
c


7
TRUE
TRUE
b,c



